# How to put a link to a text that redirect me to a certain place? [See Inside]

Tags: html

I want to put a link to it a text but to a certain place in one page

and not in another link or .html file.

for example i have **benefit 1** in the top of the page and i have **benefit 2** in the bottom of the page. What i want is when i click **benefit 1** it will lead/direct me too **benefit 2** in the bottom of the page.

does anyone know how to do that?
if yes ty! :D

Comment: In the future make sure to make some own research first before asking a question. You probably should read [ask].

Comment: I did but i didn't quite understand...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check any HTML documentation on line - for instance [W3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp).

Here's a link within a page making you jump to the page top:

```
<html>
<body>

<h2><a id="top">Some heading</a></h2>

<p>Lots of text....</p>
<p>Lots of text....</p>
<p>Lots of text....</p>

<a href="#top">Go to top</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**Edit**

More explanation: in the link (anchor) you use `#` + `uniqueId` (here it is named '#top') and then in the target element you add just the `uniqueId` (here it is 'top').

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use any plugins then,you can just give the the **benefit 1** in a anchor tag and and give the id of the **benefit 2** container in the href.

```css
.one{
  height:1000px;
  background:red;
  width:100%;
  
}
.two{
  height:200px;
  background:green;
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="one">
<a href="#google">google</a>
</div>
<div id="google" class="two">

</div>
```

Comment: The answer should be here not only in fiddle.